Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Printing on both sides to Xerox Phaser 6510 Postscript printer does not work
Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Printing on both sides to Xerox Phaser 6510 Postscript printer does not work
I have had this problem before last time I updated to 22.04 LTS Then I fixed by setting double sided printing in at least three places, in the print dialogue in settings -> printers and in the seperate Printer Settings. I have it set now in at least four places, including the CUPS settings and it still does not work. I have had to resort to using my phone to print files double sided. I have tried printing from the commmand line and many different applications all to no avail.
Is there anybody out there with a postcript printer who has managed this on 24.04 LTS?

I managed this in the end by installing the printer as an IPP Anywhere in CUPS and I was able to print from Okular at least double sided.
